# ArcGIS Pro parallel processing

Tags: arcgis-pro

In `ArcGIS Pro 3.03` the user can select the processing/parallel processing factor under `Analysis > Environments > Processing Factor`. Will this speed up each and every tool/process or just the ones that support it?

If not then is there a way to force it?

Purpose: Summarize area of smaller polygons inside bigger multipart polygons. Since, the smaller polygons are some `2.3 million` and the bigger polygons are `34` (and the data sits on a network drive), I am looking for a way to speed up the `Summarize Within` tool. I have an Intel Core i9 so, I have a lot of cores to spare.

Comment: The first line of [Parallel Processing Factor (Environment setting) - ArcGIS Pro | Documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/environment-settings/parallel-processing-factor.htm) addresses one of your questions:  "Tools that honor the Parallel Processing Factor environment will divide and perform operations across multiple processes."  And no, there is no way to force a tool that doesn't support it to support it.

Comment: If your data is a shapefile make sure it has a spatial index, that can significantly improve performance or better still ensure the data is in a file geodatabase.